# First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model. How can I get an user's id to the User model?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to make a favorite functionality where an user can add other users as their favorites.
In the View where the profile of an user is shown I have a button that adds an user or removes it if it was already added.
The problem is that I can't pass to the views the user that will be added as a favorite.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_type1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
...

class Type1(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    favorite = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name='favorite')
```

views.py

```
def FavoriteView(request, pk):
    current_user = request.user
    Type1.user = current_user.id
    buser = Type1.user
    Type1.favorite = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.POST.get('username'))  # The of the error where I try to add the user being added as a favorite
    fuser = Type1.favorite
    if Type1.favorite.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        Type1.favorite.remove(request.user)
    else:
        Type1.favorite.add(request.user)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile-details', kwargs={'username': Type1.favorite}))


class UserView(DetailView):
    model = User
...
    template_name = 'users/profile-details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        favorite_connected = get_object_or_404(Type1.favorite, id=self.kwargs['username'])  # The of the error where I try to add the user being added as a favorite
        favorite = False
        if favorite_connected.favorite.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        data['user_is_favorite'] = favorite
        return data
```

profile-details.html

```
...
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="{% url 'favorite' object.id %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
  
        {% if user_is_favorite %}
            <button type="submit" name="favorite" value="{{object.id}}">Not favorite</button>
        {% else %}
            <button type="submit" name="favorite" value="{{object.id}}">Favorite</button>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Log in to add user to favorites.</a><br>
  {% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
    path('profile/<str:username>/', UserView.as_view(), name='profile-details'),
    path('favorite/<str:username>/', FavoriteView, name="favorite"),
```

Comment: Which of these lines do you get that error on? Do you get the same error on both? This part `get_object_or_404(User, id=request.POST.get('username'))` looks correctly formed to me.

Answer (score 0):

One immediate problem I see is that your URL path wants a string for the username, but your URL for the form gives it the ID of the user, so that'll be an `int`.

In terms of your error, you're trying to pass a username, but I don't think that'll be in the POST data. However if it was, you should be able to do;

`get_object_or_404(User, username=request.POST.get('username'))`

However, based on my initial comment, you should probably just get the user by ID like you are doing, but use the PK of the user which is comes with your view;

`get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)`

You may also come across more errors, because you're assigning an object, if it exists to `Type1.favorite` and then attempting to do `Type1.favorite.filter(` which will fail. You can only `.filter()` on a queryset, not a model instance.